# Rethinkdb restore defects on CentOS 6.7

Tags: python, rethinkdb, centos6.5

I've needed to reinstall my rethinkDB cluster (the works, OS etc), and before i did that i made a dump, which i'm now trying to import.

So, now i have the rethinkDB cluster up and running and have transferred the dump file.

But i get errors in the restore command.

## Preamble:

Went from CentOS 7.1 to CentOS 6.7.
Python client installed, python version is 2.6 on CentOS 6.7.
reThinkDB RethinkDB 2.2.3-1

Running three instances on the same server via:

> sudo nohup rethinkdb --directory /data/redb1 --bind all &
>
> sudo nohup rethinkdb --port-offset 1 --directory /data/redb2 --bind
>   all --join localhost:29015 &
>
> sudo nohup rethinkdb --port-offset 2 --directory
>   /data/redb3 --bind all --join localhost:29015 &

## The problem:

When running the following command:

> sudo rethinkdb restore rethink_dump.tar.gz -c localhost:28015 --shards 1 --replicas 1

I get:

```
Unzipping archive file...
  Done (8 seconds)
Importing from directory...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/rethinkdb-import", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('rethinkdb==2.2.0-2', 'console_scripts', 'rethinkdb-import')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 299, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2229, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1948, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/rethinkdb/_import.py", line 161
    res["create_args"] = {k: getattr(options, k) for k in ['shards', 'replicas'] if getattr(options, k) != 0}
                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Error: rethinkdb-import failed
```

Anyone know where this goes wrong?

Dumping from reThinkDB works.

It looks like a python compatibility error, but i'm coming from ORA/MSSQL (yes, looking into FOSS driven by spending money on people instead of licenses)

Cheers

Stevns

Comment: This was indeed a python compatibility problem.  I opened an issue for this on the RethinkDB Github issue tracker [here](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/5294).  As a workaround (until the new version of the python driver is released), you could use python2.7+, install the python driver from the github repo, or apply the diff to your python driver yourself.

Comment: When do you think the new driver will be released?

Comment: Should be within one or two days.

Comment: The new python driver was released a couple hours ago, let me know if you run into any more problems.